# Hibernate cache in grails domain class

Tags: hibernate, caching, grails

I have a domain class in grails 1.5 that represents data from a table that seldom changes. How can I configure hibernate's cache so the class accesses the table let's say only once per hour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop an ehcache.xml into grails-app/conf. You can take one, for instance, from `%grails_home%/lib/ehcache-core-XXX.jar`, ehcache-failsafe.xml.

In defaultCache tag, put in `timeToLiveSeconds="3600"`.

Though, cache won't give you an absolute guarantee - for instance, it won't pre-cache, and some instances can be pushed out.

**EDIT**: In case you're interested in per-class caching strategy, [a sample](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=10721):

```
<cache name="org.appfuse.model.User"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    overflowToDisk="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to use a different cache configuration for a specific class ?

Comment: Sure, it's a per-class sample.